# How many times does a loop run in Batch with a pool of 2?

Tags: matlab, batch-processing

I have a for loop, that generates a 1 by n array, and then saves that array as a mat file called "Batch_Test_N (For Loop Iteration Number)". If I were to run this in batch with a parallel pool of 2, is each mat file generated 2 times, or is each loop run once? For example, does worker 1 run through the entire for loop, and then worker 2 also runs through the entire for loop, or does worker 1 only do iteration 1,3,...9, and worker 2 does the rest?

```
for i=1:10
    filename=['Batch_Test_',num2str(i)];
    Array=ones(1,i);
    save(filename,'Array')
end
```

```
job=batch('Script_Name','Pool',2)
```

Comment: You can test this easily yourself. It will run once, one just one worker. If you want to distribute the iterations over multiple workers, use a `parfor` loop instead of `for`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw  the `parfor` loop, I was just not sure if it would work in my case. In reality, I have 3 `for` loops, 2 nested, and some calculations are done inside the final one. Would making the first `for` loop a `parfor` loop work? Essentially the `for` loops are just varying the parameters of the calculations. You said that I could test this myself, how would I do that?

Comment: Yes, change the outer-most loop to a `parfor`, leave the inner loops. I meant you could just run the code in your post and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@David already gave the correct answer in a comment, this answer is just to expand a little on that.

When you run `batch('<script>', 'Pool', N)`, it's basically as if you ran

```
parpool(N);
<script>
```

in MATLAB - in other words, your script gets executed with an open parallel pool of size N. Note therefore that `batch(..., 'Pool', N)` uses `N+1` workers on the cluster.

Therefore, as @David correctly points out - to get parallelism on the cluster, your script needs to contain parallel language constructs such as `parfor`, `spmd`, or `parfeval`.This is described in the doc: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/run-a-batch-job.html#bu62o45

Comment: I read about `parfor`, but i had a few nested loops which I read wouldn't work. So what I did was create an array with all of my parameter combinations, and just inputted that into the `parfor` loop. Thank you.